# Haskell List Comprehension: Boolean Item in List used as predicate

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am writing a function `majority`.

The function returns `True` if at least two of the parameters are `True`.

The function returns `False` if at least two of the parameters are `False`.

The function can be written like this:

```
majority :: (Bool,Bool,Bool) -> Bool
majority (True,True,_)=True
majority (True,_,True) = True
majority (_,True,True)=True
majority _ = False
```

Alternatively, a list comprehension can be used:

```
majority' (x,y,z) = length [b | b <- [x,y,z] , b] >= 2
```

I don't fully understand why this second solution works.

I know that this means we will take `b` such that it is one of `[x,y,z]` and `b` applied to `b` must be `True`. The length of this list must be greater than or equal to `2`.

Does the `b` in the predicate (the third `b`) change its value for that it is equal to `x`, then `y` and then `z`. Or, does `b` always have the value of `x`?

I tried:

```
majority'' (x,y,z) = length [b | b <- [x,y,z] , True] >= 2
```

I found that this always returned `True`,even when the function should return `False`.

Also, I noticed that

`[b | b <- [False,True,True] , True]` would return `[False,True,True]`

And in general,

`[b | b <- [x,y,z] , True]` would return `[x,y,z]`

However,

`[b | b <- [False,True,True] , b]` would return `[True,True]`

And in general,

`[b | b <- [x,y,z] , b]` would return a list of `True`s which is as long as the number of `True`s in `[x,y,z]`

This explains why

```
majority'' (x,y,z) = length [b | b <- [x,y,z] , True] >= 2
```

always returns `True`. The inequality is always `True`, because the list `[b | b <- [x,y,z],True]` always has a length of `3`.

Why does using `b` as the predicate work in?

```
majority' (x,y,z) = length [b | b <- [x,y,z] , b] >= 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't fully understand why this second solution works.

Let us first focus on the list comprehension:

```
[b | b <- [x,y,z] , b]
```

Here we create a list `[x, y, z]` and we will enumerate over it, with `b` as enumerator. It thus looks to some extend like a `for` loop in Python for example.

The next part, the `b` at the right of the list comprehension is a *filter*. This means that it will only yield a result if `b` is `True`. This thus means that if `[x, y, z]` is `False, False, True`, then the list comprehension will yield one `True`, since the filter `b` will reject the first two items, since then `b` is `False`.

We thus construct a list of `True`s: all items in the list will be `True`, but we are not that interested in what the items are in the list. We are interested in the *number* of items the list comprehension produces. We thus make use of [**`length :: [a] -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:length) to determine the number of times `x`, `y`, and `z` are `True`. This thus means that:

```
length [b | b <- [x, y, z], b]  -- number of True's in [x, y, z]
```

If that number is greater than or equal to two, then we thus know that there are at least two `True`s.

Comment: Would writing `length [b | b <- [x, y, z], b==True]` have the same meaning then?

Comment: @overworkedstudent: yes, but `x == True` is a bit non-sensical, since it is equivalent to `x`, and thus is only longer.

Comment: @overworkedstudent When `n` in an integer but we need a boolean value, we often resort to a comparison such as `n == 42`. However, when `b` is a boolean and we need a boolean value, there is no need to use a comparison like `==`: we already have the value we need: `b` (or, at most, `not b` if we need to negate it).